# Place Column into the center of a csv file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to figure out what I need to do to get a field placed in to a csv file but not at the end.  I have field1, field2, field3, field4.  I need to put a field in the middle of these fields .. field1, field2, ,NEWFIELD, field3, field4.  I have this code but it places it at the end.

```
$objTable | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation $AttachmentPath

# get the file content
$csv = get-content $AttachmentPath

# add two columns to the header row
$csv[0] += ",AD_Site_Name"

# write the changes back
$csv | out-file c:\scripts\test.csv

#import new csv with new columns
import-csv c:\scripts\test.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$objTable | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation $AttachmentPath

Import-CSV $AttachmentPath | 
 Select Field1,Field2,NEWFIELD,Field3,Field4 |
 Export-CSV c:\scripts\test.csv
```